# Replace django TestCase class with django-nose

Tags: python, django, nose

I would like to have a nose plugin that if enabled will just generate an HTML page with all the tests run which contain also the request/responses for each test.

This would be useful to generate some documentation FROM the tests.

Now I don't think it's too hard, but to do that I guess I have to intercept the self.client.get/post/whatever methods.
To do that however it looks like I have to replace the default TestCase class with something else, and I would like to not force any project that wants to use this tool to do have to do that.

This kind of works for example

```
  import json
  from mock import patch

  from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
  from django.test import TestCase
  from django.test.client import Client


  class DebuggingClient(Client):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super(DebuggingClient, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

      def get(self, url, *args, **kwargs):
          print("Calling endpoint {} with args {} and kwargs {}".format(url, args, kwargs))
          response = super(DebuggingClient, self).get(url, *args, **kwargs)
          print("Obtained response {}:{}".format(response.status_code, response.content))
          return response


  class TestSimpleApi(TestCase):
      # TODO: how do I make this happen inside the plugin??
      def _pre_setup(self):
          super(TestSimpleApi, self)._pre_setup()
          self.client = DebuggingClient()

      def test_getting_numbers_returns_list_of_first_numbers(self):
          url = reverse('gen_numbers')
          response = self.client.get(url)
          self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
          data = json.loads(response.content)
          self.assertEqual(data, list(range(10)))
```

But I would like do do that just depending on a nose-plugin enabled.
Any idea how? I can't find a way to change the base class just from a nose-plugin (unless maybe doing some crazy monkey patching).
The project is here by the way even if far from working yet..

https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/django-docs-from-tests